# sort by count in json

Tags: python, django, json, tastypie

I'm using tastypie to create json from my django models however I'm running into a problem that I think should have a simple fix.

I have an object Blogs wich has Comment object children. I want to be able to do something like this with my json:

/api/v1/blogs/?order_by=comment_count

But I can't figure out how to sort on a field that's not part of the original comment/ blog model. I create comment_count myself in a dehydrate method that just takes the array of comments and returns comments.count()

Any help would be much appreciated - I can't seem to find any explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly this should help:

```
Blog.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments')).order_by('comment_count')
```

Comment: Yes! Actually I just discovered that in the documentation. However for some reason the result of that query is taking a ridiculously long time to return....is that normal?

Comment: @9-bits I haven't used in on large datasets so can't say for sure. I don't think it should be "ridiculously" slow.

Comment: What if I want to use different order_by fields?

Comment: @Burak You can just replace `Count('comments')` with `Count('someotherfield')`. The `comment_count` is just your own variable name, you can change it to whatever or leave it unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it with [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) like something like:

```
Blog.objects.extra(
    select={
        'entry_count': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog_entry WHERE blog_entry.blog_id = blog_blog.id'
    },
    order_by = ['-entry_count'],
)
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work. The caveat is it will only work with a relational database.